# How to iterate over data got by GET method?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to loop over table but nothing is displayed. ApiService is working correctly.

Model:

```
export interface LoginAndPassword {
    id: number,
    username: String,
    user_password: String,
    grade: String,


    comment: String
}
```

Part of class with function:

```
loginData: LoginAndPassword[] = []

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers();
  }

 public getAllUsers(){
    this.apiService.getLoginandPassword().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loginData = res;
        for (let i=0; i<this.loginData.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.loginData[i].username)
      }
        console.log("get this")
      },
      err =>{
        alert("err");
      } 
    );
  }
```

Comment: How do you know the ApiService is working correctly? What's `res` look like before you loop?

Comment: And do you really have an API returning the password of all the users. Ouch!

Comment: Try to output to the console the response in `tap` function, maybe loginData is not itterable.

Comment: Somehow my Rest Api was dead and I didn't notice it, sorry for waste your time.